# Why I have many "\\" after submit django form?

Tags: django, json, postgresql

I have django form from model

parameters = fields.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

key, value - input field

After submit Into the database I can see:

""\"\\"{\\\\"interface\\\\": \\\\"USB, PS/2\\\\", \\\\"color\\\\": \\\\"black\\\\", \\\\"warranty\\\\": \\\\"24\\\\", \\\\"dpi\\\\": \\\\"800\\\\"}\\"\"""

Why I have many "\\" symbols?

Thank you very mach.

Comment: What're your PostgreSQL and Django versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON has been through multiple passes of backslash escapes.

Taking off the outer quotes:

```
"\"\\"{\\\\"interface\\\\": \\\\"USB, PS/2\\\\", \\\\"color\\\\": \\\\"black\\\\", \\\\"warranty\\\\": \\\\"24\\\\", \\\\"dpi\\\\": \\\\"800\\\\"}\\"\""
```

Removing one level of backslash escapes and outer quotes:

```
"\"{\\"interface\\": \\"USB, PS/2\\", \\"color\\": \\"black\\", \\"warranty\\": \\"24\\", \\"dpi\\": \\"800\\"}\""
```

Removing another level of backslash escapes and outer quotes:

```
"{\"interface\": \"USB, PS/2\", \"color\": \"black\", \"warranty\": \"24\", \"dpi\": \"800\"}"
```

And one last pass gives us the actual JSON:

```
{"interface": "USB, PS/2", "color": "black", "warranty": "24", "dpi": "800"}
```

So the real question is **what code is generating this?** And why are you expecting JSON from a form?